# How to scatter pyspark.sql.DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I only find that `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame` can scatter.

ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html

What is the relationship between `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` and `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame`?

Can I convert `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` to `pyspark.pandas.DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily convert Spark DataFrame to Spark Pandas DataFrame using the `to_pandas_on_spark` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.to_pandas_on_spark)) or `pandas_api` ([doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.pandas_api.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.pandas_api)) functions (depends on the Spark version - the latter is in Spark 3.3+).

Answer (score 0):

To address your second question, seems like you just need [`toPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html) ?

```
df = spark.range(500).selectExpr("rand() as col1", "rand() as col2")

df.toPandas().plot.scatter(x="col1", y="col2", figsize=(5, 3)); #adjust the params here
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
+-------------------+-------------------+
|               col1|               col2|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|0.30635985539888333| 0.4870719189567285|
|0.42598409012829175| 0.7952023956810078|
|0.11566134855017962|  0.526445377673446|
| 0.9904776216970759|0.21399932251819465|
|  0.745479774526823| 0.9353658749650922|
+-------------------+-------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```